Trouble setting up a shared component (in a different package) for 1 or more React Native Apps
I am running into trouble with a React Native app.
Right now I have this file structure:
Outer Folder
Packages
----ReactNativeApp1
--------All standard files for React Native App
----shared (Folder for shared components)
--------Button.tsx sample component.
I ran npx react-native start to initialize this folder, then I created the Button.tsx file (source below):

import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
const Button = ({ text, onPress }) => {
return (

{text}

);
};
export default Button;

My goal is to have one root folder, 2+ inner folders that represent React Native Apps, and a Shared folder that will hold code common to all the apps.
I have an App.tsx file inside ReactNativeApp1/App1 that properly registers the component, and imports the button:
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Button from '../shared/Button';
 
const App1: React.FC = () => {
return (
    <View>
      <Button text="Press Me" onPress={() => console.log('Button pressed!')} />
    </View>
  );
 };
 
export default App1;

However, whenever I try to run the app, I get this error:
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ../shared/Button from C:\Users\username\VSCode Projects\SampleReactNativeSharedProject\packages\ReactNativeApp1\App.tsx:
None of these files exist:

..\shared\Button(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
..\shared\Button\index(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

1 | import React from 'react';
2 | import { View } from 'react-native';
3 | import Button from '../shared/Button';
I have tried many things:

Creating 2+ apps and Shared components folder
Common troubleshooting techniques, like clearing the cache, print statements
Searching the internet for "React Native Monorepo"
Using ChatGPT to generate Sample code
Watching youtube videos related to this issue
Switching from NPM to Yarn + Yarn Workspaces
Installing shared components as dependencies for App1 (and other apps)

However, it seems like I am stuck on this same issue either way.
I want to have all my projects (in subfolders) in one root folder, and a shared components subfolder too.
I would appreciate any help on this issue, and am happy to share more details.

This is a common issue when working with monorepos. first, create a package.json in the root ofthe project and configure it to use yarn workspaces:
package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "ReactNativeApp1",
    "shared"
  ]
}

make sure both reactnativeapp1 and shared have their own package.json
now install dependencies:
yarn

next, configure the metro bundler for the structure of the monorepo
metro.config.js // this should be at the root of project
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  watchFolders: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'shared')
  ],
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: {
      shared: path.resolve(__dirname, 'shared')
    }
  }
};

after this, inside the ReactNativeApp1, create a metro config file to extend the root config
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg', 'ts', 'tsx']
    },
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer')
    }
  };
})();

now import in App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Button from 'shared/Button'; //  alias shared as in metro.config.js

const App1: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button text="Press Me" onPress={() => console.log('Button pressed!')} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App1;

Now start the bundler by resetting the cache
npx react-native start --reset-cache or yarn start

Alternatively you can use Nx workspace which is a commonly used tool for maintaining a monorepo workspace. Read more here : https://nx.dev/recipes/react/react-native
